# How to authenticate for login

Tags: django

How I can authenticate my user for login ,here authenticate does not work properly

I have used authenticate for login

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.models import Signup
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

def signup(request):

    if request.method=="POST":
        obj=Signup()
        obj.username=request.POST.get('username')
        obj.password=request.POST.get('password')
        obj.save()
        context={'username':'username'}
        return render(request,'basic_app/singup.html',context)
    else:
        return render(request,'basic_app/singup.html')
def login(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponse("you have login")
        else:
           return HttpResponse("wrong password or username")
    else:
        return render(request,'basic_app/login.html')
```

Comment: Are you using django's `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` model for creating new users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should login using `login` after authenticating.

```
user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get('username',''),
                        password=request.POST.get('password',''))
login(request, user)
```

Read:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in

Comment: would you explain more what is going on here I am new in   Django **user = authenticate(username=request.POST.get('username',''),
                        password=request.POST.get('password',''))** why i have to validate again when I have authenticated before and why i should use **login(request,user)** please explain **and also after doing this it is not working @Vishal .R**

Comment: Authenticate just verifies if there is an user with the given set of credentials in your database. It returns None if the authentication system raises PermissionDenied exception. However, it does not logs the user in to the system. You have to use login to do that. The page that i linked, solely deals with authentication and might be useful for you.

Comment: About your change in the comment that this didn't work, what does the user object contain. Was the authentication successful. If not, what was the error? Try updating the content of the error

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use Django's inbuilt LoginView ("https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView")

If you want to change the layout style. Either override the Django login template or override the class view.

For overriding the class view:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
class MySignInView(LoginView):
    form_class = MySignInForm
    template_name = 'mylife/myrules/login.html'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your following code :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from basic_app.models import Signup

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout 

from django.http import HttpResponse,HttpResponseRedirect 

from django.urls import reverse

from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def login(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        password=request.POST.get('password')
        user=authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user:
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponse("you have login")
        else:
           return HttpResponse("wrong password or username")
    else:
        return render(request,'basic_app/login.html')
```

1) When you authenticate your username and password, it just returns User and it doesn't make you to login,

2) for login you have to call login(requst,user),it will create session in your database as acknowledgment